# Get text in quotes

Tags: php, text, quotes

is there is some function that can take just text inside the quotes from the variable?
Just like:

```
$text = 'I am "pro"';
echo just_text_in_quotes($text);
```

I know that this function doesn't exist.. but I need something like that.
I was thinking about `fnmatch("*",$text)`
But this cant Echo just that text, It's just for check.
Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function will return the first matched text between quotes (possibly an empty string).

```
function just_text_in_quotes($str) {
   preg_match('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);
   return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : FALSE;
}
```

You could modify it to return an array of all matches, but in your example you use it within the context of `echo`ing its returned value. Had it returned an array, all you would get is `Array`.

You may be better off writing a more generic function that can handle multiple occurrences and a custom delimiter.

```
function get_delimited($str, $delimiter='"') {
    $escapedDelimiter = preg_quote($delimiter, '/');
    if (preg_match_all('/' . $escapedDelimiter . '(.*?)' . $escapedDelimiter . '/s', $str, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

This will return `null` if no matches were found.

Comment: Thank you, that was what i need.
Well, I've never used regular expression, but it seems I will need it alot in my project...
I will accept it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

[`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is made for this

```
   preg_match('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $quoted_string);
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($quoted_string);
   //return array of all quoted words in $str
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
"(\w*)"
```

will help you as you can see here: http://rubular.com/r/3kgH7NdtLm