# PHP String Split between quotations

Tags: php, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get text in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635657/get-text-in-quotes)

I have a string ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]
I want it to only return what is inside the quotations.

Comment: why not just a substr operation to strip off the first 2 and last 2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with a capturing group:

```
if (preg_match('/\["(.*?)"\]/', '["xx.xx.xx.xx"]', $matches)) {
  echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this out a few minutes ago. Thanks.